# How do I trigger AKS cluster auto scaling when the node volume limit is reached

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

In Azure Kubernetes Service, the number of Azure Disks you can attach to a Node depends on the VM size. Eg. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv4-dsv4-series. See the data disks column.

I have pods that attach a disk using the `disk.csi.azure.com` provisioner.
This works as long as there are less then 4 concurrent pods like that.
The fifth stalls and errors out, because the VM size we use only supports 4 disks.

How can I schedule pods with the disk limit in mind, such that the auto scaler scales up the cluster when the disk limit is reached on all the nodes?

Based on [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#extended-resources) I hoped AKS would expose this limit as an extended resource, but there is no hint of it in the `capacity` status of the nodes.
[Affinities](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) seem to be binary rules for putting pods on the node; I see no way to model "at most x pods that do y can go to a node".

Edit for context: The pods are CI jobs generated by gitlab-runner. I want to use persistent volumes as build areas to avoid having to clone the entire project from scratch in every job. From the point of view of Kubenernetes this looks like dynamically generated Pods, each of which requests to mount one of a previously defined set of Persistent Volume Claims. The PVC:s are fungible (they cache the same clone), but the configuration forces us to request one by some specific name for each pod.

Update: I am exploring a solution based on [Extended Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/extended-resource-node/). I tried setting them based on the VM size label via Kyverno, but it seems that Kyverno's support for mutating existing resources does not work for the status subresource. Or at least my configuration successfully updates labels on existing nodes, and extended resources on new nodes, but does not set extended resources on existing nodes. Here's my attempt:

```yaml
apiVersion: kyverno.io/v1
kind: ClusterPolicy
metadata:
  name: azure-disk-resource-limit
spec:
  mutateExistingOnPolicyUpdate: true
  background: true
  rules:
  - name: add-disk-limit
    match:
      any:
      - resources:
          kinds:
          - Node
          - Node/status
    mutate:
      targets:
        - apiVersion: v1
          kind: Node
        - apiVersion: v1
          kind: Node/status
      patchStrategicMerge:
        metadata:
          labels:
            kyverno-dummy: "babar1"
        status:
          capacity:
            kyverno-dummy: 9
#      patchesJson6902: |-
#          - path: "/status/capacity/kyverno-dummy"
#            op: add
#            value: 8
```

NB: I had to edit the Kyverno settings to enable changes to Nodes: 1) I changed the resourceFilter and removed the filter that was hiding Node. 2) I gave the background and admission controllers the right to edit nodes:

```yaml
# In values.yml for the kyverno chart:
admissionController:
  rbac:
    clusterRole:
      extraResources:
        - apiGroups:
            - ''
          resources:
            - nodes
            - nodes/status
            - namespaces
          verbs:
            - update
            - patch
backgroundController:
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
  rbac:
    clusterRole:
      extraResources:
        - apiGroups:
            - ''
          resources:
            - nodes
            - nodes/status
            - namespaces
          verbs:
            - update
            - patch
```

I'm at the point where I'm considering the creation of a custom controller for setting the extended resource, but that doesn't feel sane.

PS. I found a UserVoice requesting AKS would add the limit automatically: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/02e94731-f824-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0.

Comment: Kindly share your deployment file, and better to use one disks to multiple pods, for each pod one disk is not good approach.

Comment: 1) Do you believe the auto-scaling should work in this scenario and there is simply something in my configuration stopping it? If not, I don't see how the precise configuration is relevant, I'm looking for a fundamental answer to how this could work. The pods are also dynamically generated by gitlab-runner, so I don't have a deployment file as such. 2) The pod needs to access specific data. (Sort of.) If there was data from multiple pods on the same disk, I would somehow have to schedule all those pods to whatever node happened to attach the shared disk.

Comment: To address the scenario where you need to manage storage and disk attachment limits in Azure Kubernetes Service , you can use Kubernetes Persistent Volumes (PVs) and Persistent Volume Claims  to handle storage in a more abstracted and dynamic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It now looks like AKS supports this out of the box.

The reason I thought it didn't was errors like this:

```
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume  2m57s (x9 over 5m9s)  attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-5c518d52-7f4d-4a02-a17f-7030bbbfd84c" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Attach volume /subscriptions/[redacted]/resourceGroups/[redacted]/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/[redacted] to instance akswin000001 failed with Retriable: false, RetryAfter: 0s, HTTPStatusCode: 409, RawError: {\r
  "error": {\r
    "code": "OperationNotAllowed",\r
    "message": "The maximum number of data disks allowed to be attached to a VM of this size is 4.",\r
    "target": "dataDisks"\r
  }\r
}
```

But when running my experiments, I suddenly faced a message like this in the events:

```
  Warning  FailedScheduling  52s   default-scheduler   0/4 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector, 1 node(s) exceed max volume count, 2 node(s) had untolerated taint {node.kubernetes.io/unreachable: }. preemption: 0/4 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod, 3 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..
  Normal   TriggeredScaleUp  45s   cluster-autoscaler  pod triggered scale-up: [{akswin 1->2 (max: 2)}]
```

Notice the **1 node(s) exceed max volume count**. So now it looks like AKS is in fact smart enough out of the box to account for the disk limit. Either the mechanism was added during the week I've been looking into this, or the fact that it failed last week was just a random hiccup. I'm leaning towards the latter explanation, since I was still able to observe the error at least once, the system just recovered from it this time (when the new autoscaled node with disk slots available came on-line). Last week it failed forever in a loop.

So, thanks everyone for answers. If you have a problem with the same shape, @Vitaly's [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77023715/321491) is probably the way to go, it but seems to be unnecessary in AKS after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can think about using S3 buckets instead of attached disks, they may be even better suited for high (unknown) number of pods requiring storage with pod-specific naming conventions.

Another possibility is to try out a topology spread constraint of the `topologyKey` "node", e.g.

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mypod
  labels:
    foo: bar
spec:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 4
    topologyKey: node
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        foo: bar
  containers:
  - name: pause
    image: registry.k8s.io/pause:3.1
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/#example-one-topologyspreadconstraint

Comment: I'm running large-scale C++ compilation here. I don't have actual measurements yet, but I have a hard time believing file shares or other higher-abstraction things mountable as file systems could have the required performance.

Comment: The trick of using topologySpreadConstraints, is intriguing. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to create a custom solution because AKS does not come with this capabilities by default.

In order to manage storage and disc attachment limits in the Azure Kubernetes Service, you can make use of Kubernetes **Persistent Volumes** and **Persistent Volume Claims**. These tools will help you manage storage in a more dynamic and abstracted manner.

1. **Understand persistent volumes and claims based on persistent volumes.**

**Persistent Volume**:  A PV is a storage unit in the cluster that has either been provided statically using Storage Classes or by an administrator. The same as nodes and pods, PVs are resources in the cluster.

**Continuous Volume Claim:** A PVC is a user's request for storage. It is comparable to a pod asking for CPU and memory. PVCs are utilised by pods and utilise PV resources.

2. **Establish Storage Classes**

If you use dynamic storage provisioning, create storage classes that outline the different "classes" of storage you want to provide. The type of underlying storage characteristics may be specified by a storage class.

**Example of a Storage Class for AKS:**

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
parameters:
  storageaccounttype: Standard_LRS
```

Apply the Storage Class to your cluster:

```
kubectl apply -f azure-standard-storage-class.yaml
```

3. Determine Persistent Volume Claims:

To request the storage you require, include PVCs in your Kubernetes pod setups. Your pods are connected to the underlying PVs by PVCs.

**Example PVC :**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: standard
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

2. Apply the PVC to your cluster:

```
      kubectl apply -f my-pvc.yaml
```

**4. Attach PVCs to Pods:**

Refer to the PVCs you've defined in your pod setups. It connects the pod to the storage that was mentioned in the PVC.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: my-container
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        - name: my-volume
          mountPath: /data
  volumes:
    - name: my-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my-pvc
```

Apply the pod to your cluster:

```
kubectl apply -f my-pod.yaml
```

Here, the PVC called "my-pvc" is being used by the pod "my-pod" to request and access storage. The storage is mounted inside the pod at the path '/data'.

**5. Scaling Pods :**

Now, if you choose dynamic provisioning, Kubernetes will automatically provision extra PVs and connect them to the new pods through PVCs when you need to scale your application by adding more pods. As a result, you may manage storage dynamically without being concerned about node-specific disc attachment restrictions.

**PODs auto scaling automatically when load increase.**

[image]

**Load Increase:**

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am attaching the disks via PVCs. This is a very nice summary of the way PVC:s work, but sadly it does not really address my case. Each pod generated by gitlab-runner will request a specific PVC, by name. The PVC is backed by an Azure disk. And then the node runs into the disk attachment limit.

Comment: It is my understanding that PVC:s automatically provisioned based on a storage class are always empty. I looked into using a StorageClass based on node-local storage, but as far as I can tell, freshly provisioned PVC:s are always empty and therefore not usable for caching across pods running at different times.